# Open" the csv file format into Excel from internet explorer 6

Tags: internet-explorer, csv

I am using Java Struts, sending it to user using the following codes

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel"); 
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileFullName);
```

Firstly I hope that this is the correct place for my question... :) I hope
that you can help me.

The error message I get when I try to open a file from Internet Explorer is

```
"C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\Local Settings\Temporary Internet
Files\Content.IE5\QXJ0P436\btbillsdfjlsfjk.csv' could not be found"
```

I am trying to "Open" the csv file format into Excel. It allows me to
"Save" the file to which ever directory I want but I don't want to do that,
I would just like to open the file. This has always worked in the past so
I'm now wondering why the file is 'missing'.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We are going to need to know how you are sending it to the user, what language are you using?

Comment: If you are sending through HTTP, what are the values of the Content-Type and Content-Disposition headers?

Answer (score 1):

Check Tools - Internet Options - General Tab - Temporary Internet files - Settings... - And check that you have enough space allocated to hold the csv file and that the path looks like the one you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Are you downloading over HTTPS?  IE can be quite buggy if the headers aren't similar to `Expires: 0`, `Pragma: cache`, `Cache-Control: private`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a programming related question, but anyways, this usually happens due to insufficient user permissions.

You might find better support at a Windows support website.

Answer (score 0):

I was having an issue similar to this and discovered that the problem was IE had issues when there was a space in the name of the file. It also had issues if the content-disposition was an attachment versus an inline file.

Content-Disposition: inline;filename=NoSpacesFileName.csv

All other browsers worked fine over HTTPS. Changing the other headers did not affect my issue.